# how to install the latest version in a branch with composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

Say I'm trying to install a package that has a 1.0 branch and a master branch. The 1.0 branch has tags like 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc.

What I want to be able to do is to install the latest version in the branch. I don't want to install a tagged release - I want to install the latest branch version.

Here's what I tried:

```
composer require package/package:1.0

composer require package/package:~1.0
```

Both of those got the most recent 1.0.* tag but not the latest in the 1.0 branch.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

For that matter what even is the difference between `1.0` and `~1.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can require `dev-master` as the version name (or dev-branchName), and it will pull in the most recent commit from the specified branch. For versioned branch names, use e.g. `2.0.x-dev` as the version name instead.

(More details are available on the [Schema - package links](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) section of the Composer documentation.)

The difference between `1.0` and `~1.0` is that `1.0` specifies a *specific* version number, and `~1.0` specifies that any version "compatible" (according to semantic versioning) with 1.0 is allowed. From the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md):

> The ~ operator is best explained by example: `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2 <2.0.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`.

There is also the similar ^ operator: `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0`.

Comment: Whenever I try to do `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:dev-2.0` I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/exuC2nPG And yet phpseclib/phpseclib does exist and has a 2.0 branch: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0

Comment: @neubert Ah, in this case you'll want to require 2.0.x-dev, instead. Sorry about that. Updated the answer accordingly.